# Create shapefile geometries from scratch using R

Tags: qgis, shapefile, r, polygon-creation

I would like to interactively create polygons from within R/RStudio. I am familiar with creating shapefiles using QGIS, but I would like to create a similar, but more streamlined workflow using R.

After googling for a bit, I was unable to find any solution to my question. Are there any R libraries to interactively create shapefile geometries over, for example, a Sentinel-2 image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can plot anything on an R graphics window you can use the `locator` function to interactively draw points and lines.

```
> plot(1:10)
> xy = locator(type="l")
```

Now click and draw something. Hit right-mouse (or maybe ESC key) to finish.

That returns a list of X and Y coordinates. Make into an `sf` object using standard `sf` functions like `st_polygon` etc.

```
> xy
$x
[1] 3.140349 3.351323 6.304949 7.060936 6.849963 3.913918 4.828136 3.386485
[9] 1.962415

$y
[1] 5.861015 7.745089 7.960972 5.861015 3.682555 2.740518 4.192825 4.408708
[9] 4.742346
```

Comment: That's amazing. Thanks so much @Spacedman. I wonder if it's possible to view the lines as you create them?

Comment: Are you using `rstudio`? Because their graphics device has a long-standing problem with this: https://community.rstudio.com/t/show-points-from-locator-as-they-are-selected/6967  - there's a solution there that loops over getting a single point from `locator` and joining the dots as it goes, but maybe its time to open a new bug report in RStudio?

Comment: Just did this: https://community.rstudio.com/t/the-locator-function-doesnt-show-as-it-goes/148324

Comment: Yes, I am using RStudio. I stumbled upon your first link as well, which is very insightful. Thanks for opening up a post on the RStudio form. Will be monitoring it. In the meantime, I will apply the above mention solution. Thanks again for your response @Spacedman.